# Weird Dativ usage with "verloren gehen"

Tags: dative

> Sie können sicher sein, dass **uns** von Ihrer eingesparten Zeit nicht das kleinste Bisschen verloren geht.

This sentence is taken from Momo, a story. What does **uns** here mean? I see it as redundant and unnecessary, but when I try to translate it, it doesn't make any sense and doesn't feel like it's contributing to the sentence. It's somewhat weird usage of Dativ. Please explain it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usage of dative is quite common in German, and there are a lot of examples for it. The dative indicates who is affected by some action. It's not that much different from the dative used together with *geben* where it tells who is the recipient of something.

In the given example, it says not only that no time is lost but also that it's the speaker and his companions who will not lose time.

Examples for a similar use of dative:

> **Mir** scheint, dass ... (It seems **to me** that...)

> Geh **mir** aus der Sonne! (Stand out of **my** sunlight!)

> Macht **mir** den rechten Flügel stark! (Last words of field marshal Alfred von Schlieffen, the dative is hard to translate into English, a common translation is: Remember, keep the right wing strong!)

Comment: The name of the construct, [Dativus commodi](https://www.wortbedeutung.info/Dativus_commodi/) could be added for looking up further references

Answer (score 5):

Without "uns", they would simply state that time does not get lost per se (as in: is indestructible). However, in the Momo story, time is treated like a kind of ware that they "collect" from people "saving" time. So instead of stating that time is not "lost" for the Universe as a whole, they say that it is not lost *for them*, i.e., the transfer of saved time happens without "friction" loss, so to speak.

> Rest assured that not the tiniest bit of your saved time gets lost *for us*.

Comment: So **uns** has here somewhat the same meaning of **bei uns**. Is this correct?

Comment: Not quite. "bei uns" would mean something along "at our place" or "in our sphere of influence". "uns geht X verloren" is like a passive version of "wir verlieren X". The closest passive form for "we lose X" I can think of is "X gets lost by us".

Comment: @Sentry Thank you I understand it this way.

Answer (score 0):

> Sie können sicher sein, dass uns von Ihrer eingesparten Zeit nicht das kleinste Bisschen verloren geht.

Vergleiche

> (a) * *Zeit von mir ging verloren.* (d.i. *meine Zeit*)

> (b) *Von der Ladung gingen 3% verloren*.

Durch den doppten Dativ "... uns von Ihrer..." erscheint eine Doppelung vorzuliegen. Schätze das hängt damit zusammen, dass ein Konstrukt wie (a) hinreichend verallgemeinert wurde, das teils als ungrammatisch gilt, andernorts bald die Regel ist. Umgekehrt könnte man wohl suchen, wo der Fehler liegt:

> c) DAT *Der Ladung gingen 3% verloren.*

> d) GEN *Der Ladung gingen 3% verloren* (d.i. *3% der Ladung*)

Vgl. eine Form des Kinderliedes *Ringelreie*, "...  wir sind der Kinder dreie"

---

Zum besseren Verständniss kann der Satz umgestellt werden

> 1. **Uns** geht kein Bisschen **von Ihrer** Zeit verloren.

.

Was eigentlich gemeint war:

> **Wir werden nicht Ihre Zeit verschwenden**

Comment: siehe Edit für die Herleitung

Comment: Ich würde statt "Wir werden nicht Ihre Zeit verschwenden" sagen "Wir werden kein Bisschen von Ihrer Zeit verlieren."

Comment: Das sagt man aber so nicht, oder? Die Aktiv-Form von *verlieren* is *verschwenden*, gerade in Bezug auf wohl grammatikalisch unzählbare Zeit.

Answer (score -1):

Im Normalfall würde nur derjenige, der die Zeit einspart (hier das angesprochene Gegenüber), diese wieder verlieren können - ohne Kontext ist natürlich nicht zu sagen, wer das Uns hier ist, und wieso diese die eingesparte Zeit verlieren können.

Im Staffellauf könnte das freilich passieren, aber da würde man sich meist duzen, oder in einem beruflichen Team, in einem Auftragsgeber/-nehmerverhältnis. Das Uns ist erstmal überraschend und daher alles andere, als redundant.

Comment: Regarding the context: According to OP, this is from the book ["Momo"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momo_(novel)), there is a Timesavings Bank. And just like a "normal" bank promises they won't lose your money you put into an account, this Timesavings Bank promises not to lose the time that people put into their accounts.

Comment: Ah, now that's clearer. Not everybody knows Momo.